# Push items to array from another php script?

Tags: php

I have a php script - "1.php" as given below:

```
<?php
$file = array("mangoes", "oranges");
print_r($file);
?>
```

I have another php script "2.php" where I want to add items to $file on "1.php". How do I use `array_push($file, "banana", "grapes");` from 2.php on 1.php?
Also, how do i clear(empty) the array?

EDIT: I am not able to update the array in 1.php while calling it from 2.php. I used `require()` and `include()` as well.

2.php

```
<?php
require '1.php';
array_push($file, "grapes");

?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php ???

Comment: @AbraCadaver I tried that ofc, Using ```include '1.php'; array_push($file, "banana");``` in 2.php but it was not updated when I tried printing it in 1.php. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Show that code for both files.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have updated my question.

Comment: Did you try `<?php` instead of `<?`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes ofc i just forgot to add it here.

Comment: What you have posted works fine.  `print_r` in file 2.php.  Also make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Instead of include which makes both 2.php and 1.php scripts run at same time. Is there a way to call as a function from 2.php to 1.php? Such as i call 2.php as a session.